# merTools predictInterval() for model with nested random effect

Tags: r, lme4

Does `predictInterval()` from the `merTools` package not like nested random effects? For example, using the `msleep` dataset from the `ggplot2` package:

```
library("lme4")
library("merTools")
library("ggplot2")
mod <- lmer(sleep_total ~ bodywt + (1|vore/order), data=msleep)
predInt <- predictInterval(merMod=mod, newdata=msleep)
```

Returns an error:

```
Error in '[.data.frame'(newdata, , j) : undefined columns selected
```

This runs fine no problem:

```
mod <- lmer(sleep_total ~ bodywt + (1|vore) + (1|order), data=msleep)
predInt <- predictInterval(merMod=mod, newdata=msleep)
```

(Well actually it gives a warning about `NA` levels in the random effect variables, but I'm not concerned about that)

### **UPDATE**

As discussed in the comments of Ben Bolker's answer below, a new version of `merTools` accounts for nested random effects. However, when I try to predict for data that contains new levels of the nested random effect, I get errors.

This works:

```
mod <- lmer(sleep_total ~ bodywt + (1|vore/order), data=msleep)
predInt <- predictInterval(merMod=mod, newdata=msleep)
```

And this works, albeit with a couple of warnings (see below for additional Q about the warnings*):

```
mod <- lmer(sleep_total ~ bodywt + (1|vore) + (1|order), data=msleep)
msleep2 <- msleep %>% mutate(vore = "omni")
predInt <- predictInterval(merMod=mod, newdata=msleep2)
```

But this does not work:

```
mod <- lmer(sleep_total ~ bodywt + (1|vore/order), data=msleep)
msleep2 <- msleep %>% mutate(vore = "omni")
predInt <- predictInterval(merMod=mod, newdata=msleep2)
```

With the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(tmp, alllvl) : undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In predictInterval(merMod = mod, newdata = msleep3) :
  newdata is tbl_df or tbl object from dplyr package and has been
              coerced to a data.frame
```

And here, `"omni"` isn't actually a new level of `vore`, but when combined with `order`, it creates new nested combinations of the variables.

If I use `"new"` or anything else that isn't an observed level of `vore`, I get similar results: It works for the non-nested version of the model, but not for the nested version.

---

*Also, should I be concerned about the warning given by the second model chunk above:

```
> mod <- lmer(sleep_total ~ bodywt + (1|vore) + (1|order), data=msleep)
> msleep2 <- msleep %>% mutate(vore = "omni")
> predInt <- predictInterval(merMod=mod, newdata=msleep2)
Warning messages:
  1: In predictInterval(merMod = mod, newdata = msleep2) :
     newdata is tbl_df or tbl object from dplyr package and has been
       coerced to a data.frame
  2: In chol.default(sigma, pivot = TRUE) :
     the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite
```

I'm going to guess the second one is a result of `vore` taking on the same value for each observation, but that shouldn't be an issue for prediction, should it? I could see it being an issue if the variable took on the same value when I was fitting the model, but don't think it should be an issue when predicting new observations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can (apparently) work around this by writing out the interaction term explicitly.  **Warning**: I haven't actually checked to make sure the resulting predictions are correct, just seen that no error is produced and the resulting object is approximately sensible ...

```
msleep <- transform(msleep,voreOrder=interaction(vore,order,drop=TRUE))
mod2 <- lmer(sleep_total ~ bodywt + (1|vore)+(1|voreOrder), data=msleep)
predInt <- predictInterval(merMod=mod2, newdata=msleep)
```

This does generate warning messages, but apparently they're due to `<NA>` values in the `vore` variable (I don't know this data set ...)

Comment: This is the correct way to handle this for now and I have checked the predictions work as expected doing this. Now I need to work on a merTools patch to allow merTools to parse nested specifications.

Comment: @jknowles, you may find some of the machinery [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/blob/master/glmmTMB/R/utils.R) useful ...

Comment: As an update, I think the development branch of merTools is pretty close to solving this in an inelegant way. If you have an immediate need that could work. I'm working toward a new CRAN release soon and hope to get this fixed for that.

Comment: @jknowles I have installed version 0.2.0, using install.packages("merTools", type="source"). Then I run the same steps in my original question, but I get a new error: > predInt <- predictInterval(merMod=mod, newdata=msleep) Error in as.numeric(data[i, 1:colIdx]) %*% coefs[lvl, 1:colIdx, ] : non-conformable arguments

Comment: Yes, this is due to a change in the `lme4` code I believe. I have just submitted a patch to CRAN that will require a more current version of `lme4` to avoid this error. If you update your `lme4` installation to the newest version it should work, or if you update to the development version of `merTools` it will force you to update `lme4` now.

Comment: @jknowles I think there's an issue with predicting new levels of nested random effects.Have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: @BenBolker, In the link you gave, there is "Sparse Schur complement (Marginal of precision matrix) .. `GMRFmarginal`". Is this a solution to "In `chol.default(sigma, pivot = TRUE)` : the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite"?