# problems simulating effects with merTools

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain predictions for an lmer object that considers tree growth as a function of treatment, tree size, and wood density. I cannot start the prediction calculations using the draw and wiggle functions because I get an error message.

```
m1<- lmer (CRgr ~ 1 + trt*swg*size + (1 |block/Plot), data= trees, verbose=T)
newData <- draw(m1, type = "average")
```

> Number of observations < 20, random effect quantiles may not be well-defined.
>   Number of observations < 20, random effect quantiles may not be well-defined.
>   Error in `[.data.frame`(merMod@frame, , i) : undefined columns selected

Thanks!

Comment: there was a recent post somewhere (maybe on SO?) having difficulty with `merTools`'s simulation functions with a complex grouping structure, i.e. `(1|block/Plot)`.  Does it work if you try `(1|block)+(1|block:Plot)`?  Or even `trees <- transform(trees,blockPlot=interaction(block,Plot)); ...  + (1|block) + (1|blockPlot)` ?

Comment: found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166173/mertools-predictinterval-for-model-with-nested-random-effect

Comment: I *think* this is a duplicate.  The linked question explains the error.  I suspect the warning message is accurate.  If you need more help, please edit your question and we'll consider re-opening ... (actually, I can't close as duplicate until the answer on the other question is upvoted or accepted ...)

Comment: I could get the predictions when I removed the nested factor and stated it as you suggested. Thanks!